# WHM - CPanel Cannoy rearrange account

Tags: cpanel, whm

Hello I have root access to my server through whm and I am trying to change the folder for one of the account domains. I researched and I think I have to rearrange the account so I went to rearrange the account section for that domain but it is not editable at all, how do I change the folder?

Comment: you menace you are want to change root directory from /home to /home2, home3 etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand your request but in order to do a rearrange of a cPanel account you need to do that from the WHM interface. In WHM you got to **List Accounts**, extend the cPanel account you want to re-arrange using the [+] sign and click on **Change Disk Partition** then select the new home partition for that account (could be /home, /home2 etc).